# Install gRPC php extension in elastic-beanstack

Tags: elastic-beanstalk, json, yaml

I need to install gRPC php extension elastic-beanstack. The way i found is to write a config file inside ".ebextensions" in order to automatically install the extension. For that I need to create yaml or json file. I need to add the following content in yaml/json file listed in the website below:

https://cloud.google.com/php/grpc

Can anyone help me to create yaml/json file in order to automate the process of extension installation?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

This might work for you but I have encountered some issues with this setup.

```
commands:
    command1:
        command: pecl7 install grpc
```

you might also want to add `ignoreErrors: true` after the last command without indentation.

Comment: It may be worthwhile to describe the nature of the "issues" you encountered, to allow others to assess whether this setup is appropriate for their situation.

Comment: My answer should work. I have two instances with this setup one of them works and the other one doesn't. I dont believe my answer deserves a downvote as I dont see anybody providing a good solution after 3 months.

Comment: @womble if this question is off topic where would be the proper place to post it